# minimal size for a rectangle in style

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm writing an application where users can mark regions on a world map. Now these regions can be very small, so that it's hard to click on them when not zoomed in.

Is there a way how I can define (e.g. in the style function) that a (rectangle) feature should always be rendered with at least e.g. 10px × 10px?

Update: some code I currently use:

on the drawing side:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: vectorSource,
  type: 'LineString',
  geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
    if(!geometry) {
      geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
    }
    var start = coordinates[0];
    var end = coordinates[1];
    geometry.setCoordinates([[
      start,
      [start[0], end[1]],
      end,
      [end[0], start[1]],
      start
    ]]);
    return geometry;
  },
  maxPoints: 2
});

draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
  var extent = e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
  extent = app.map.rlonlate(extent); // own function to convert it from map coordinates into lat/lon
  // some code to save the extent to the database
});
```

and on the displaying side:

```
vectorSource.addFeature(
  new ol.Feature({
    geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(app.map.lonlate(extent)),
    // … some more custom properties like a display name …
  })
);
```

the style function:

```
function(feature) {
  return [new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: feature.get('mine') ? '#204a87' : '#729fcf',
      width: 2
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + (feature.get('mine') ? '0.5' : '0.2') + ')'
    })
  })];
}
```

Comment: You could show some relevant code, specially `ol.interaction.Draw`.

Comment: @JonatasWalker well, it's not about when drawing but when displaying the rectangle on a (world) map. Let's say I create a rectangle around Berlin and then I display it on a world map. There it will be just 1px × 1px in size (+ the width of the border)

Comment: But how is the workflow? Some user create a rectangle and save it to GeoJSON?

Comment: The user creates a rectangle, I save the extent (as lat_from, lat_to, lon_from, lon_to) to a database and then on some other page I show a world map with the rectangles painted to it. Users should be able to select one of those rectangles on the world map by clicking on it, but some of the rectangles are so small, that they are very hard to hit when not zoomed in far enough. I want them to be easy clickable on every zoom level.

Comment: I insist that this is about the drawing moment and you should show some relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a style function is a good idea. The second argument of the style function is `resolution` which you can use to check if your feature geometry would be smaller than e.g. 10 px at the current resolution:

```
var styleFn = function(feature, resolution) {
  var minSizePx = 30;
  var minSize = minSizePx * resolution;
  var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();

  if (ol.extent.getWidth(extent) < minSize || ol.extent.getHeight(extent) < minSize) {
    // special style for polygons that are too small
    var center = new ol.geom.Point(ol.extent.getCenter(extent));
    return new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: center,
      image:  ...
  } else {
    // normal style
    return defaultStyle;
  }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ukc0nmy2/1/